# Array type in SQlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm in the middle of developing a small site in Python. I use flask and venv.
I am currently in the middle of writing the data base and here is one of my tables:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    message_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    session_id = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    application_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    participants = db.Column(db.Array())
    content = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

The problem is in line 5:
"Array".
There is no such variable type.

I want to create a list of message recipients. Is there an Array or List variable type in SQlite?

If so, what is and how is it used?

And if not, how can I make a list of recipients anyway?

Anyone know?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

`SQLite` does not support arrays directly. It only does Ints, Floats and Text. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) the type it supports.

To accomplish what you need, you have to use a custom encoding, or use an FK, i.e. create another table, where each item in the array is stored as a row. This would get tedious in my opinion.

Alternatively, it can be done in SQLAlchemy and you will want to have a look at the [PickleType](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

```
array = db.Column(db.PickleType(mutable=True))
```

Please note that you will have to use the `mutable=True` parameter to be able to edit the column. SQLAlchemy will detect changes automatically and they will be saved as soon as you commit them.

Also, have a look at the [ScalarListType in SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.scalar_list) for saving multiple values in column.

**Update:**

In `SqlAlchemy` You can use [array column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY).

For example:

```
class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_array = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Integer())

# You can easily find records:
# Example.my_array.contains([1, 2, 3]).all()
# You can use text items of array
# db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Text())
```

**Update: This doesn't work in SQLite, SQLAlchemy's ARRAY type is for Postgres databases only. The best alternative for most people would be something involving JSON or switching to Postgres if possible. I'll be attempting JSON myself.** credit to the replier in the comments.

Comment: I tried the "PickleType" as you suggested, but I received an error message:     participants = db.Column(db.PickleType(mutable=True))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mutable'

Comment: Can you try without it?

Comment: Of course I can, but that will create another problem for me - I won't be able to edit the column, will I?

Comment: See my new update. It seems like my earlier solution is no longer valid in sqlalchemy.

Comment: This doesn't work in SQLite, SQLAlchemy's ARRAY type is for Postgres databases only.

Comment: @Xevion this was answered with the best of my knowledge at the time. I am not sure what has changed since then, nor do I know if this even worked since the OP didn't reply after my response. If you can find an answer, feel free to answer it.

Comment: Just saying in-case anyone is confused by the question's parameters and this addendum's suggestion. The best alternative for most people would be something involving JSON or switching to Postgres if possible. I'll be attempting JSON myself.